# Can't use more than one delegate in platform specific project with DependencyService?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, delegates

I have a `IService` in Xamarin.Forms which looks like so:

```
namespace MyProject.Main
{
    public delegate void XChanged();
    public delegate void YChanged();
    public delegate void ZChanged();
    public interface IOrientationSensor
    {
        double X { get; set; }
        double Y { get; set; }
        double Z { get; set; }

        event XChanged OnXChanged;
        event YChanged OnYChanged;
        event ZChanged OnZChanged;
        void Start();
        void Stop();
    }
}
```

I was first trying put my delegates into the interface - but Visual Studio complained about it - so I read they could be put into the namespace instead.

Now in my `Service`, iOS implementation I can fire `OnChangedX`:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OrientationSensor)) ]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public class OrientationSensor : IOrientationSensor
    {
        CMMotionManager motionManager = new CMMotionManager();
        NSOperationQueue queue = new NSOperationQueue();

        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }

        public event XChanged OnXChanged;
        public event YChanged OnYChanged;
        public event ZChanged OnZChanged;

        public void Start()
        {
            motionManager.StartDeviceMotionUpdates(queue, DataUpdated);
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            motionManager.StopDeviceMotionUpdates();
        }
        void DataUpdated(CMDeviceMotion data, NSError error)
        {
            if (data == null)
                return;
            // OnChangedX() works
            // OnChangedY() crashes
            // OnChangedZ() crashes
        }
    }
}
```

Firing Y and Z crashes with message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

... while firing X works.

Can someone help trying to explain why I seem to limited to only using only 1 delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I had assigned an event handler to `OnXChanged`, but not to `OnYChanged` and `OnZChanged`. Assigning event handlers apparently gives the event values:

```
public static void UseSensors()
{
    var orientationSensor = DependencyService.Get<IOrientationSensor>();
    orientationSensor.OnXChanged += () =>
    {

    };
    /* did not realize these where needed for OnChangedY and OnChangedZ to stop being null
    orientationSensor.OnYChanged += () =>
    {

    };
    orientationSensor.OnZChanged += () =>
    {

    };
    */
    orientationSensor.Start();
}
```